# Ruby on rails + angular + devise - Multiple roles / user models safety concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am building a project on ROR with Angular JS frontend and ROR API backend. I started from this example app: https://job-tracker-checklist.herokuapp.com/#/login

To the example app I added an extra user model (admin). I was able to show a different menu for admin users with Angular JS:

```
<div ng-if="signedInAsAdmin()" ng-include="admin-nav.html"></div>
```

This loads a menu if admin is logged in. One of the menu items is to state admin.customers:

```
.state('admin.customers', {
      url:'admin/customers',
      templateUrl: 'admin/customers.html',
      controller: 'CustomersController'         
    })
```

This works perfectly. However, this doesn't lock access to the page to admin users only. Anyone could access the page /admin/customers and have this template show up (even if it is without any data because the backend API checks for authentication as well).

I don't want to expose this screen at all, I'd rather redirect a user directly to login page if the user is not authorized.

The only solution I know of to do this is to check in javascript if the user is authenticated as admin user, and if he is not, redirect the user. According to my research I can do this with $stateChangeStart event in Angular. So before the state is changed, check the authentication and act upon the results of this.

However, **is this safe?** I'm not an expert on this, but can't this easily be manipulated since it is all client side?

What is a common and safe way to do this? Relying only on Javascript with the $stateChangeStart seems not safe to me? Any help, tutorials or info would be highly appreciated!

**Update**

I just realised that I think it is impossible to keep the templates away for non authorized users, which I consider to be the trade-off for using a client side framework as Angular js. I mean, if someone would inspect our state definitions they can see the link to the template file and download the HTML file. So for admin specific template files, I am not sure how to handle this. I don't want our users to be able to see titles 'applied customer discount'. Guess there is no way around this? Only way around I can imagine is render crucial template stuff server side (fetch the  HTML from an API controller action which only returns data if authenticated). I would love to hear some ideas on this!

Comment: Ultimately all you can *really* do is restrict what the server side sends over; for SPAs this is almost always data. You could conceivably send over a different application bundle, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks a lot for your reply. So how do common SPA applications written in AngularJs handle this when they need to have multiple authentication roles? I can imagine many projects don't want users snooping around in all the admin specific templates? Or is it not really common to write such a multi-userrole app in Angular solely?

Comment: The number of roles is largely irrelevant. Ultimately it's the data that needs to be protected, and the view layer, since it's basically JS, is rarely relevant without its associated data (plus the DOM itself is difficult to retrieve on its own). I *personally* don't have a problem with people accessing routes that are useless without their data, but that's just me: a Very Secure App would probably just use different JS assets altogether and decide at runtime based on server-side auth/auth which to return to the client, but I'm just guessing--sorry!

Comment: Thanks Dave :) I agree that security wise it really comes down to data protection. However, in our case I'd rather keep the admin Angular templates private as well. I love the architecture of an API backend with SPA frontend, but I can't fit both an administrative portal and customer portal into one SPA I guess if I really want to protect the administrative templates. Maybe I create 2 different SPAs 1 for admin and 1 for user, on the same ruby backend API. That will give me a little more freedom around securing eveything. I'm going to do some more research :) Thanks again!